# Substantially improved question not getting reopened

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24684668/is-the-fork-join-framework-a-bad-match-for-the-java-8-streams-api/24685855) on StackOverflow was closed as "Primarily opinion-based" even though at its core it contained a valid question. It suffered from overly conversational tone and lacked a clear request for an official, authoritative answer.

I have substantially improved the question and believe that, in its current state, it is a no-brainer reopen candidate. In the meantime I have also provided an answer which presents the requested official statement on the topic. The answer was accepted and has a score of 2.

After all the improvements I have submitted a reopen vote, but within 24 hours there seems to have been no further moderator activity regarding the question's status.

I would like to inquire what exactly is going on with the question—is it not appearing in reopen queues (due to some filtering policies I am not aware of), or is it being continually passed on by moderators as undecided? Maybe there is something still wrong with the question?

Comment: "More specifically, does Oracle have an official position regarding the limitations of the F/J Framework as applied to the parallelization of streams processing? If so, does it have plans to do something about them?" - This doesn't feel like it can ever be on-topic on SO. The first question is somewhere between resource request and speculation, and the second one is basically the same but worse - what value would an answer like "Oracle says they want to do X" have? That's not a hard fact, just a vague promise at best...

Comment: @l4mpi Asking for authoritative/official answers has never been considered as a "resource request", even less as asking for "speculation". And second, it is still a hard fact that Oracle has official plans to do something. Say it was a bug, and a user asked if the bug was officially confirmed, with plans to fix it, that would be a legitimate request. In this specific context, Oracle's offical position on the intended area of application of the Streams API is a crucial concern which every user should be aware of.

Comment: "Say if it was a bug, and a user asked if the bug was officially confirmed" - that would actually be off-topic as well IMO as it's a meta-question. A question like "I want to do X but can't because of this bug, what are my options" would be fine, but "does this company have this bug in their issue tracker" does not seem useful. The same for "does oracle have plans for X" - how is that useful? How does them having or not having plans influence the available solutions to a specific problem, except for maybe adding the option to wait an unspecified time until they've implemented their plans?

Comment: @l4mpi The question could be off-topic on the grounds of not dealing with a specific problem, but it is not off-topic on the grounds of asking for an outside resource or soliciting speculation. But notice further that the main point of this subject has a very practical consequence to any user of the Streams API---and *that* is on-topic for SO. Any question asking about poor performance/out-of-memory happening when parallelizing an IO-backed input source may potentially be resolved by reading the answer I have provided.

Answer (score 6):

You indeed did a great job editing the post, substantially lifting the question quality.

However, that question now looks like it should be migrated to Programmers, instead of being reopened on Stack Overflow.

It is not a practical problem with code, it is question about concerns over a framework, so reviewers may feel hesitant reopening it.

I've flagged it for moderator attention, requesting it be migrated.

Comment: On the other hand, there are lots of questions on SO which are as general as this one, yet as a rule, the community finds them perfectly acceptable and on-topic. Recent example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764118/lambda-vs-anonymous-inner-class-performance-reducing-the-load-on-the-classloade Combine that with a strong practical value of my answer (it contains an important message pertaining to a very broad class of use cases), and I cannot see that particular aspect as a reason to close as off-topic.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I did not say it was outright off-topic, but it would be *much better suited* to Programmers.

Comment: Anyway, it seems that the question keeps lingering in the On Hold limbo :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: the [review verdict](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/5290966) was to leave it closed; it is no longer in the review queue.

Comment: I see... I thought that in that case, my vote would be annulled, but I still see "reopen (1)". That confused me.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: It has not been annulled, but the post will get *far less attention*. All that *Leave Closed* votes do is remove it from the review queue.